# retrieve undone commits VS2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

I had a bunch of pendening changes in my local VS project. I made some more changes that i wanted to undo, so i right clicked undo on my soultion.

And boom, the project is blank.

I have lost around 2 days of work becuase i guess i didnt make an initial commit.

Is there anyway i can get this lost work back or am a up a creek without a paddle?

I have tried to ctrl-z and view history.

View history only showed the that i added the project files, no other history.

Comment: You are up a creek without a paddle unless you have some other backup tool. You should learn to commit early, commit often. Work in small stages, and commit each stage. Check in the file explorer just to be sure though but most likely the files are gone.

Comment: Well... you undid them... you normally do that when you don't care anymore, so those files are gone

Comment: Yep it's my fault, i hadnt worked on the project for a couple of months and i thought i had commited that last changes i made. 

Turns out i didnt. 

Live and learn i guess.

Comment: Use a tool like Runtime Getdataback to scan your drive. It has been a useful tool for me on many occassions.